# Word Cloud in Python

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, word-cloud

Have a dataframe:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHS1n.png)

Using the following code but get ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0.

Does anyone know how to fix this; I am trying to generate 3 word clouds one for all tweets one for real tweets and one for fake tweets.

Thank you for the help in advance :)

```
df_real = df[df['label']==1]

df_fake = df[df['label']==0]

tweet_All = " ".join(review for review in df.Tweet)

tweet_real = " ".join(review for review in df_real.Tweet)

tweet_fake = " ".join(review for review in df_fake.Tweet)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize  = (30,30))
# Create and generate a word cloud image:
wordcloud_ALL = WordCloud(max_font_size=50, max_words=100, background_color="white").generate(tweet_All)
wordcloud_ADR = WordCloud(max_font_size=50, max_words=100, background_color="white").generate(str(tweet_real))
wordcloud_NADR = WordCloud(max_font_size=50, max_words=100, background_color="white").generate(str(tweet_fake))

# Display the generated image:
ax[0].imshow(wordcloud_ALL, interpolation='bilinear')
ax[0].set_title('All Tweets', fontsize=30)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[1].imshow(wordcloud_ADR, interpolation='bilinear')
ax[1].set_title('Tweets under real Class',fontsize=30)
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[2].imshow(wordcloud_NADR, interpolation='bilinear')
ax[2].set_title('Tweets under fake Class',fontsize=30)
ax[2].axis('off')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df['label'] seems to be of type str (or object): In your screenshot it shows "fake" as entry. Maybe df_real and df_fake are empty?
I would try to show the head of df_real and df_fake.

One solution could be to replace the first lines with

```
df_real = df[df['label']!='fake']
df_fake = df[df['label']=='fake']
```

Comment: Hi, What I am trying to do is to show a word cloud associated with real tweets and fake tweets. Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean better in terms of performance? Basically your solution should work. Did the hint help?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you

Comment: However, performance wise the two word clouds for real and fake were very similar. Do you know how to plot word frequency?

Comment: In the created wordclouds, words that occur more frequently are displayed larger. If that is not enough, there are many options, depending on the application. You might want to display the most common words in a bar chart? However, there are other starting points for improvement. You could begin with a stopword filter, for example.

Comment: I have included stop words already but I am struggling to show the top 10 words in a bar chart for all tweets, real tweets and fake. And suggestions?

Comment: Divide all texts into words, count the frequencies, select the 10 most frequent ones and plot them.
There are many ways to approach these steps. I like matplotlib!